# Redirect after sign in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to the web side of dev (been doing mobile), I'm using firebase.auth() to sign a user in.  I'm wondering how I should be building my page redirection into my javascript/node.

What is proper js code for directing to a new page after a task is completed?

The code I'm trying looks like this

```
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {

    console.log("hey");

    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    //Sign In
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    window.location="/index3.html"
  });
```

Solution code that is now working:

```
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {

    console.log("hey");

    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    //Sign In
    // const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    // promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
   //  window.location="/index3.html"
   auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
        .then(function() {
            window.location.href = "/aftersign";
            // window.location.assign("/index3");
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
  });
```

I have a separate .js file the defines my redirects so /aftersign redirects to index3.html.

Comment: Does your code work? When you assign a new url to the location property it is supposed to call location.assign().

Comment: it doesn't appear to be working at the moment no

Comment: how can I check to see if location.assign() is being called?

Comment: If you don't do the redirect inside a `.then()` handler, redirect will happen whether or not `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` was successful or not. `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` returns a promise that will take an unknown amount of time to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following by targeting the promise "success" handler `then()` of the promise returned by Firebase method `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`. `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` is an asynchronous action returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). With how the code is structured now, the redirect could happen before `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` has completed and also when an error has occurred. Performing the assignment of `window.location` inside of `.then()` ensures the login was successful before any redirect action happens.

You can use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) methods such as `assign(somePath)` or setting the value of `window.location.href`.

```
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    //Sign In
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
        .then(() => window.location.href = "/index3" /* window.location.assign("/index3") */)
        .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
});
```

Depending on the browser's your targeting, lambda statements such as `e => console.log(e.message) may not be available, instead it would look like:

```
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    //Sign In
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
        .then(function() {
            window.location.href = "/index3";
            // window.location.assign("/index3");
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        });
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Yea thanks this worked.  I just realized I was having issues getting things to work because I was using browserify to bundle my modules and I was only editing the original .js files not the bundles.   I do have one more question, I'm getting "unexpected token" for the .catch when I add .then.  Otherwise its working now

Comment: Glad to help! That was entirely my bad, typing too fast. I've update the `then()` statements. The "unexpected" token was coming from an semicolon `;` character after the `then()` statement, there should NOT be one there when using with a `catch()`. Thanks!